# Django Rest Framework serializer doesn't get CharField

Tags: python, django, serialization, django-rest-framework

I've built an API using Django and Django Rest Framework. In my serializer I defined an `organisation` which can be posted, but needs to be stored to a different model. I defined my serializer as follows:

```
class DeviceSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    geometrie = PointField(required=False)
    organisation = serializers.CharField(source='owner.organisation')
    owner = PersonSerializer(required=False)

    class Meta:
        model = Device
        fields = (
            'id',
            'geometrie',
            'longitude',
            'latitude',
            'organisation',
            'owner',
        )

    def get_longitude(self, obj):
        if obj.geometrie:
            return obj.geometrie.x

    def get_latitude(self, obj):
        if obj.geometrie:
            return obj.geometrie.y

    def create(self, validated_data):
        print("ORG:", validated_data.get('organisation', "NO ORG FOUND")) # 
        # Do some custom logic with the organisation here
```

But when I post some json to it, which includes an `organisation` (I triple checked the input), it prints the line `ORG: NO ORG FOUND`.

Why on earth doesn't it forward the organisation?

[EDIT]

The model code:

```
class Person(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    email = models.EmailField()
    organisation = models.CharField(max_length=250, null=True, blank=True)


class Device(models.Model):
    geometrie = gis_models.PointField(name='geometrie', null=True, blank=True)
    owner = models.ForeignKey(to='Person', on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True, blank=True, related_name='owner')
```

and the test code:

```
def test_full_post(self):
    device_input = {
        "geometrie": {"longitude": 4.58565, "latitude": 52.0356},
        "organisation": "Administration."
    }
    url = reverse('device-list')
    self.client.force_login(self.authorized_user)
    response = self.client.post(url, data=device_input, format='json')
    self.client.logout()
```

Comment: Hi, @krammer65. Could you please provide your models?

Comment: And your test code?

Comment: Probably not related but it seems like you should be [SlugRelatedField](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/#slugrelatedfield) for the organisation.

Comment: Does your `PersonSerializer` has extra logic? Could you please add `PersonSerializer` implementation to question?

Comment: I'm afraid, that source is only for serializing, not deserializing. https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields/#source
`source=` can be useful, when you call `serializer.serialize()`, not `create()`.
You should modify your json to 
```
device_input = {
    "geometrie": {"longitude": 4.58565, "latitude": 52.0356},
    "owner": {
        "organisation": "Administration."
    }
}
```

Comment: Also, I advice you insert also `print(validated_data)` to understand which data presented and in what format.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the line:

```
print("ORG:", validated_data.get('organisation'], "NO ORG FOUND"))
```

to this:

```
print("ORG:", validated_data.get('organisation', "NO ORG FOUND"))
```

Comment: Good point. Thanks for spotting that. I fixed it, but unfortunately that was just a copy pasting error and it's not the problem.

Comment: Could you paste the json in the question?

Answer (score 0):

Since you have added the **`source`** argument, DRF automatically push the **`organisation`** data into a ***nested level***
So, if you want to access the **organisation** data, try the following,

```
class DeviceSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    organisation = serializers.CharField(source='owner.organisation')

    # other code stuffs
    def create(self, validated_data):
        organisation = validated_data['owner']['organisation']
        print("ORG:", organisation)
```

Comment: If input json is `{
        "geometrie": {"longitude": 4.58565, "latitude": 52.0356},
        "organisation": "Administration."
    }`, then owner will be empty. validated data will contain only geometrie field, without owner or organization.

Comment: I have tested the above solution with **DRF 3.10.3**

Answer (score 0):

Pls, try 'StringRelatedField'.

```
class DeviceSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):

    geometrie = PointField(required=False)
    organisation = serializers.CharField(source='owner.organisation')  # yours
    # ----------------
    organisation = serializers.StringRelatedField(source='owner.organisation')  # try this.
    owner = PersonSerializer(required=False)

    # your code
```

Comment: StringRelatedField is for __str__ representation of related field. And, again, source is about serializing data, it's not related to deserialization.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using a serializer field with dotted notation `validated_data` will be:

```
{
'geometrie': {'longitude': 4.58565, 'latitude': 52.0356}, 
'owner': {'organisation': 'Administration.'}
}
```

Hence, you can access organisation as `validated_data['owner']['organisation']`

However, if you want to **serialize** a attribute/column of a another related table/foreign key you need to do use `StringRelatedField` [ 
`organisation = serializers.StringRelatedField(source='owner.organisation')` ]
This would ensure that the 'Device`instance fetched from the database contains the proper`organisation`attribute during a`GET` request.

**Deserialization** won't work though and you would need additional implementation in the `create` method. This is because you need to create a `Person` instance (with the `organisation`) and then connect the `Device` instance to that newly created instance.

A concrete example can be found here:
[Writing nested serializers](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/#writable-nested-serializers)